# Header file compatibility between Ubuntu and OS-X

Tags: c++, linux, macos, prototype

I just finished up a class in C/C++ in a Linux environment and when I copied over and ran some simple codes on my Mac (OS-X 10.7 Lion), I ran into some errors. I use gcc/g++ on both platforms. It seems that the prototyping isn't transferring properly: when I prototype the mysin.cpp file, it spits out the errors below, but when I copy the function definition in its place (i.e. put all code in one file), it works fine.

output:

```
J-MacBook-Pro jh$ g++ -o main main.cpp -lm
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "mysin(double, double)", referenced from:
      _main in cc67Vpm6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

mysin.cpp

```
#include <math.h>

double mysin(double x, double tol) {

  int N;
  int ii = 1;
  double q;
  double sN = x;
  double cont = x;
  double term = x;

  while (fabs(term) > tol) {
    term = term * (-x * x) / ((2 * ii + 1) * (2 * ii));
    sN = sN + term;
    ii = ii + 1;
  }

  return sN;

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

double mysin(double x, double tol);

using namespace std;

int main(){

  cout << "sin(1) = " << mysin(1, 1e-6) << endl;

}
```

It seems like the problems are with some type of name mangling, but I can't really tell what's going on. Any ideas? Something incredibly obvious I'm missing?

Comment: You need to include mysin.cpp into the compilation so that the definition of your function `mysin` can be seen by the linker. Try `g++ -o main mysin.cpp main.cpp -lm`

Comment: Side note (doesn't solve the problem): Don't duplicate prototypes; use a header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to compile in two stages or compile all c files in one go like

```
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -o mysin.o -c mysin.cpp
g++ -o main main.o mysin.o -lm
```

or

```
g++ -o main mysin.cpp main.cpp -lm
```

Otherwise g++ will look only at the main.cpp and cannot find your mysin function

Comment: ...of course. the new error messages just threw me off. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's a linker error. When you compile and link main.cpp, the linker complains that it cannot find the definition(the compiled code) of your double mysin(double x, double tol), as you havn't told the compiler where that is.

So, compile both your source files, then link them together:

```
g++ -c -Wall mysin.cpp -o mysin.o
g++ -c -Wall main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -o main main.o mysin.o -lm
```

(You might be able to also just do g++ -Wall -o main main.cpp mysin.cpp -lm)